# Adding a theme to Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to add some theme/template design to my documentation and I was wondering if there was any way to add a line of HTML on line 20 of every HTML page generated by Sphinx?

Answer (score 1):

You can [build a custom theme](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/theming.html) (consider simply copying a default theme) and modify/override the appropriate template files. What exactly do you want to accomplish?